# Unexpected large execution time with two identical sql queries

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I would be grateful to someone how can explain me this case http://pastebin.com/YBQTwxYG, both queries are almost identical, but second is executed ms except first almost 3 min.

As EXPLAIN shows second query uses correct indexes, but first doesnt.

I am very confused.

Comment: Please always add your code to your question. It is an integral part of your question and thus belong there (and is hard to read in the pastebin). At first glance, I think you are right, it is using the wrong indexes (but that actually depends on your data, though I don't see a reason for 3 minutes with your numbers). Try replacing your `inner join`s with a `straight_join`, this should give you the same execution plan in both queries. Try `optimize tables post_article, content_post, ...` to recreate your statistics. Try `select count(*) from ...` without `limit 15` for both queries.

Answer (score 0):

First some formatting:

```
SELECT  c.`id`, c.`content_id`, c.`author_id`, c.`text`, c.`typotext`,
        c.`created`,
        p.`id`, p.`html_title`, p.`permalink`,
        u.`id`, u.`username`, u.`first_name`, u.`last_name`, u.`avatar`
    FROM  `content_comment` AS c
    INNER JOIN  `content_post` AS p  ON (c.`content_id` = p.`id`)
    INNER JOIN  `post_article` AS a  ON (p.`id` = a.`content_id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `auth_user` AS u  ON (c.`author_id` = u.`id`)
    WHERE  c.`deleted` IS NULL
      AND  a.`id` IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY  c.`created` DESC
    LIMIT  15
```

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `post_article`, then it cannot be `NULL`.  Hence, the test is unnecessary.

If you meant to test `auth_user`.`id`, then `LEFT` is unnecessary.

Then check that you have these composite indexes:

```
c:  INDEX(deleted, created)  -- in that order
a:  INDEX(content_id, id)    -- in that order
```

The second query *is* different in that it accesses `forum_topic` instead of `auth_user`.  A look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for those two tables may explain why you got different explain plans.  If not, check `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

If you need further discussion, provide those `SHOWs` for all 5 tables.